# Trying to get date value from a Material UI Textfield

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im trying to get Two date sfrom Two textfields using material UI, in order to submit to a rest api and get results.
Im having some problems with the Dates because when i pick any date, its making the "submit" and i only want to submit when clicking the submit button.

```
<form
            onSubmit={this.formHandler(this.state.formFields)}
            style={{ display: "inline-flex", padding: "15px" }}
          >
            <Grid item xs>
              <TextField
                id="from"
                label="De"
                type="date"
                name="from"
                //value={this.name}
                defaultValue="2017-05-24"
                className={classes.textField}
                InputLabelProps={{
                  shrink: true
                }}
                formatDate={from => moment(from).format("DD-MM-YYYY")}
                //onChange={handleChange1.bind(this)}
                onChange={e => this.inputChangeHandler.call(this, e)}
                value={this.state.formFields.from}
              />{" "}
            </Grid>{" "}
            <Grid item xs>
              <TextField
                id="date"
                label="Até"
                type="date"
                name="to"
                //value={this.target.value}
                defaultValue="2017-05-24"
                className={classes.textField}
                InputLabelProps={{
                  shrink: true
                }}
                formatDate={date => moment(date).format("DD-MM-YYYY")}
                onChange={e => this.inputChangeHandler.call(this, e)}
                value={this.state.formFields.to}
              />{" "}
            </Grid>{" "}
            <Grid item xs>
              <Button
                type="submit"
                variant="contained"
                className={classes.button}
              >
                Submit{" "}
              </Button>{" "}
            </Grid>{" "}
          </form>


inputChangeHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let formFields = { ...this.state.formFields };
    formFields[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    this.setState({
      formFields
    });
    console.log(formFields.from);
    console.log(formFields.to);
  }

  formHandler(formFields) {
    axios
      .post("/api/register", formFields)
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        //Perform action based on response
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
        //Perform action based on error
      });
  }
```

How can i prevent this ?
Can anyoen help since i think i have to do the same thing for other 3 components and will probably have a negative impact on my app please?

Answer (score 0):

This is happenning because **you are not supposed to pass data as argument of your onSubmit function**:

```
onSubmit={this.formHandler(this.state.formFields)}
```

You can access your state inside the formHandle as the [`React Form Documentation`](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html)  suggests.

Change your onSubmit to something like this:

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
```

And then in your submit function you can access your state:

```
handleSubmit(event) {
   event.preventDefault();

   // access your state here
   this.state.formFields
}
```